# check whether elements at particular indexes are equal or not in java 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of arrays like

```
String [][]mixedArray={arrperson1,arrperson2,arrperson3,arrperson4,arrperson5};
```

and each of the array inside it has elements like :

```
String[] arrperson1={"111","Sameer","Roy","samro@gmail.com","12-Apr-1990","64567","8888","Kolkata"};
String[] arrperson2={"333","Pranoy","Roy","praro@gmail.com","12-Apr-1990","64577","8888","Asansol"};
```

I am able to traverse and print all the elements by the following code :

```
for(int i=0; i<mixedArray.length;i++) 
{
    for(int j=0;j<mixedArray[i].length; j++) 
    {
                System.out.println("Values at arr["+i+"]["+j+"] is "+mixedArray[i][j] );
    }
}
```

But I need to find out whether the elements at arr[0][1], arr[1][1], arr[2][1] are equal or not by comparing them with each other. And if equal, the count of how many of the elements are equal is also needed.

Comment: please format your code. It's virtually impossible to make any sense out of it.

Comment: which version of java you are using ?If java 8 then you can use Streams

Comment: You could try it with `Collectors.groupingBy`.